# When working on a new feature over several days, how do I manage commits?

Tags: git, git-commit

I’m working in a feature branch for the last few days. The feature involves various files including templates, stylesheets, and JavaScript modules (both client and server). I will soon complete the feature (it will be in alpha stage), but until then, the involved files are pretty much in flux, so it doesn’t make sense to commit anything.

I don’t like how my work isn’t committed (“saved”) over night, so I do a temporary “WIP” (work in progress) commit, and then `git reset HEAD^` to revert it whenever I continue work the next day. That way I can do a proper commit whenever the feature reaches alpha stage.

This approach does seem like a hack though, so I’m wondering what I should do instead. Is there a standard way in Git to handle these types of situations?

Answer (score 4):

You could commit as often as you need and use a `git rebase --interactive` before pushing so your *n* commits become only one (or two...).

See also: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html